# Continue with a method that returns a task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I would like to execute three steps of work. One prepare task, one work task that is encapsulated in a method returning a task and a clean up task that requires results from the previous step. But I am not sure whether  I did it the proper way with unwrapping and accessing the 'Result' property or if there is cleaner version of including the method in the execution chain.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine("Prepare"))
                .ContinueWith(x => Work())
                .ContinueWith(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Unwrap().Result));
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static Task<string> Work()
{
    Thread.Sleep(1500);
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => "See my results...");
}
```

Comment: Why not do them in a same task? What benefits you get by doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [Rackspace Threading Library](https://github.com/rackerlabs/dotnet-threading), it's easy to ensure operations are performed with the desired semantics. In addition, it handles canceled and faulted tasks in predictable ways (a daunting feat when you aren't using `async`/`await`, to say the least).

- Use [`Select`](http://rackerlabs.github.io/dotnet-threading/docs-latest/html/Overload_Rackspace_Threading_CoreTaskExtensions_Select.htm) for continuations that do not return a `Task` (either a value, or `void`)
- Use [`Then`](http://rackerlabs.github.io/dotnet-threading/docs-latest/html/Overload_Rackspace_Threading_CoreTaskExtensions_Then.htm) for continuations that return a `Task` or `Task<T>`

Example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task operation = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine("Prepare"))
        .Then(_ => WorkAsync())
        .Select(resultTask => Console.WriteLine(resultTask.Result));
    operation.Wait();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static Task<string> WorkAsync()
{
    return DelayedTask.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1500))
        .Select(_ => "See my results...");
}
```

---

If you still want to use the TPL directly, then the *main* problem (aside from cancellation and exception handling) with the original code is the placement of the call to `Unwrap`. You actually would want to place it as you see in this code:

```
// NOTE: I WOULD NOT USE THIS CODE
// (preferring the Threading Library or async/await instead)
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine("Prepare"))
                .ContinueWith(x => Work()).Unwrap()
                .ContinueWith(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Result));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions about the placement of Unwrap. I wont do it like that in production code. At the moment I am just tring to get a better understanding of continuations.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply have an async method that executes all the steps and returns a Task:

```
static async Task DoAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Prepare");
    Console.WriteLine(await WorkAsync());
}
```

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DoAsync().Wait();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I was trying to make up an example to use continuations. Your solution would definitly work.